# Using FullCalendar methods with AngularUI wrapper

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I'm trying to integrate AngularUI's calendar wrapper into my application, and the calendar initialization works fine. However, I don't see how I can call calendar methods from here. Here's my controller code:

```
$scope.events = [];
$scope.calendarOptions = {
    calendar: {
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    $scope.events.push({
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    });
                });

            }
            // should call 'unselect' method here
        },
        editable: true
    }
};
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```

How do I call methods from the calendar? It's not in my controller's scope, I've checked everywhere inside the scope object.

I found this inside the uiCalendar directive code:

```
 scope: {ngModel:'=',config:'='},
```

By my understanding, this means that the calendar is created in an isolated scope. So no methods can be called on the calendar. HOWEVER, in the demo I found this line:

```
 /* Change View */
$scope.changeView = function(view) {
    $scope.myCalendar.fullCalendar('changeView',view);
};
```

So the demo can call methods on the calendar and I can't? I can't replicate this either.

Any help understanding or fixing the issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it was pretty obvious in the source code, but I didn't understand on first glance. Here's a relevant snippet:

```
if(attrs.calendar){
    scope.calendar = scope.$parent[attrs.calendar] = elm.html('');
}else{
    scope.calendar = elm.html('');
}
```

This binds the calendar to the parent scope under the name that you declare when you write the calendar directive in your HTML. e.g.

```
<div ui-calendar="options" calendar="my-calendar-name" ng-model="events"></div>
```

This means I can call on the calendar's methods in my controller's scope. It was a feature implementation that I hadn't even considered yet! We need some docs for this script.

Comment: we have gone over this functionality here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @joshkurz Nope, there's no documentation on this functionality there, and the documentation that is there is limited to passing config options to the calendar for initialization. I understand that most of the docs needed are provided directly from Arshaw's site, this is all that's needed to link the two. Pull request submitted, thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I added the calendar="myCalendar" attribute, but when I called $scope.myCalendar.fullCalendar('render'), I got "TypeError: Cannot call method 'fullCalendar' of undefined". ui-calendar="calendarConfig" and ng-model="eventSources" attributes transfer just fine to $scope.calendarConfig and $scope.eventSources, but not the calendar object. Do I need to do something else to inject it into the controller?

Comment: It sounds to me like you did that part correctly, I suggest posting your code on another question and linking the question in a comment here. Then I (or anyone else) can help you better. Also double-check everything was setup as per @joshkurz link above.