# Highcharts content in bootstrap carousel is not auto-resizing to carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I have a high chart as content div content on a second item within bootstrap carousel.  It resizes fine if its on the first carousel slide/item.  However, if the highchart is on the second slide it doesn't resize when it slides in.

How can I autoresizse carousel content if not the first visible carousel slide/item?

Here is the jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/ARYAv/

```
<div class="content" >
     <div class="hero-unit" >
         <div id="mainCarousel" class="carousel slide">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <h2 style="padding-left: 22px">Hello1</h2>
                <div id="container2" class="container-main">click for next slide that doesn't autoresize</div>
                <a style="margin-left: 22px" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Hello1 &raquo;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <h2 style="padding-left: 22px">Hello2</h2>
                    <div id="container" class="container-main"></div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Hello2 &raquo;</a> 
            </div>
            </div>              
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mainCarousel" data-slide="prev" >&lsaquo;</a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mainCarousel" data-slide="next" >&rsaquo;</a>
     </div>
  </div>                
</div>

.container-main {
    display: block; 
    height: 540px; 
}
```

Comment: Cause your problem occurs on the second slide read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17115808/1596547

Comment: your second container, don't have a class 'container-main' like the first have. Try to add this and add a width:100% like `.container-main {
    height: 540px; 
    width: 100%;
}`

Comment: Problem is that second element has style: `display:none` so when creating chart width of that chart is NaN/0 -> in that case default value for Highcharts chart is 600px.

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/aPEVy/20/ I added display:block but no go.  What am I missing?  Width: 100% didn't seem to resize correctly and ran off carousel. thx

Comment: No, I mean that items in carousel are not visible, see: http://jsfiddle.net/aPEVy/25/ (items have display set) - container for Highcharts is visible, and it works - of course in that case carousel doesn't work. What you can do? When carousel comes to Highcharts resize chart using `chart.setSize()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and used the following solution to size my chart:

```
$('#chart-carousel').bind('slid', function() {
    $("#value-stats").highcharts().setSize(500, 350);
});
```

By binding the `slid` event - which signals a completed slide of the carousel - to the `setSize()` method of the chart, the chart gets resized properly.

Two points:

1. There's is a visual effect as you see the chart actually change size when the slide is completed.
2. I tried to work it out with dynamic sizing using `container.height` and `container.width` but this had no effect at all hence the hard coded sizes. Not ideal but at least my charts get properly sized.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's an old question, but I stumbled upon the same problem and found a solution using Highcharts [reflow](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow) function.

If all charts have the class `container-main`, you can do something like this:

```
$('.carousel').carousel().on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.container-main').each(function(){
            $(this).highcharts().reflow();
        });
    }, 1);
});
```

Hope this will help somebody.