# jqplot doesn't render when calling from inside panel-collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqplot, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Background**

I have just decided to upgrade my Django app to bootstrap 3, and after changing my accordions to panels, I found out that the Jqplot that used to work before, is no more working. I have three accordions as a group, and each of them contains a Jqplot script, and also a div in which the plot has to be displayed.

This is how the skeleton looks:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
          First Heading
        </a>
       <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          // generic jqplot barchart that goes like this...
          // var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', s1, {...
          });
        </script>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div id="chartdiv"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The same thing goes on for two other `panel panel-default` divs. (Two more plots written in the same way.)

**Problem**

It's in this line:
`<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">`

When I have a panel collapsed with `class="panel-collapse collapse"`, it's collapsed like expected but the plot is not generated even though `document.ready()` inside it is getting called.

However, if I have it as `class="panel-collapse collapse in"`, the panel is not collapsed, and plot is also generated.

**Question**

I need to have first panel un-collapsed and other two collapsed by default, but when I am doing so using the classes mentioned above, the second and third plots are not being generated (specifically, Jqplot canvas is not generated).

I guess this must have something to do with Bootstrap 3 and its changes to accordion, because it used to work in my old app (which used older version).

How can I get over this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to generate the plots on document.ready cause the collapsing only hide content by css. Read this question [fullcalendar not visible until button is clicked or window resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994673/fullcalendar-not-visible-until-button-is-clicked-or-window-resized/17115808) maybe it will helps you too.

To generate content "live" on collapse consider the the events of the collapse plugin, see: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage. You could try to generate the plot on shown.bs.collapse for example.

To be sure also read: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/