# Collapsible accordion not showing content when initialized collapsed

Tags: jsf, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using twitter bootstrap with JSF-2.2.4 and Spring 3.2.4 Framework. I've built a collapsible accordion based on the following tutorial: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse
The code seems to work fine, but only if I start with opened accordions, meaning that I add the 'in' class to the div which inherits the content which is supposed to be collapsed. If I remove the 'in' class the accordion is opened by clicking the appropriate link, but the content is no displayed.
Content is plot created with plotfaces.
Any ideas?

Edit: I just tried filling the box with an image. This seems to work. Maybe this helps narrowing down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this plotfaces work, but i expect your problem similair to [fullcalendar not visible until button is clicked or window resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994673/fullcalendar-not-visible-until-button-is-clicked-or-window-resized/17115808)

Try to set `.collapse {display;block; visibilty:hidden;}` instead of display none. If this don't helps try to focus on the height of the element. The plugin change the height from `0` to `auto` but on initial load the height is not set.